# Changing redundancy in Recovery Services Vault?

Tags: azure

I created Recovery Services Vault in Azure and didn't see any option to choose from GRS or LRS. I am told it uses GRS by default. How can I change it to LRS?

Answer (score 0):

That's right, GRS is the default option but you can change it.

From **Proprieties** of your vault > **Backup Configuration** > **Update**

Note: if you already have VMs protected, you shall delete them and backup them again.